# Best way to write this program

Tags: java, big-o

I have a general programming question, that I have happened to use Java to answer. This is the question:

Given an array of ints write a program to find out how many numbers that are not unique are in the array. (e.g. in {2,3,2,5,6,1,3} 2 numbers (2 and 3) are not unique). How many operations does your program perform (in O notation)?

This is my solution.

```
int counter = 0;


for(int i=0;i<theArray.length-1;i++){
for(int j=i+1;j<theArray.length;j++){
    if(theArray[i]==theArray[j]){
        counter++;
                    break; //go to next i since we know it isn't unique we dont need to keep comparing it.
            }
}
}

return counter:
```

Now, In my code every element is being compared with every other element so there are about n(n-1)/2 operations. Giving O(n^2). Please tell me if you think my code is incorrect/inefficient or my O expression is wrong.

Comment: what are the requirements?  You can nearly always do a speed/memory tradeoff: it all depends on what your requirements are.  You could copy the array to another array, sort its elements in *(n log n)* and then find in one pass over the sorted array how many elements are duplicated.  Now if your array of ints only contains small integers, a "bucket sort"-like algo could solve your problem in *O(n)*.  It really depends on the requirements.

Comment: It's just a textbook question. It didn't really mention any other requirements than I stated. The textbook didn't give an answer.

Comment: @JJG is this a homework question? You should tag it as such if so.

Comment: No. I'm just going through textbook questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a `Map` as in the following example:

```
// NOTE! I assume that elements of theArray are Integers, not primitives like ints
// You'll nee to cast things to Integers if they are ints to put them in a Map as
// Maps can't take primitives as keys or values
Map<Integer, Integer> elementCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
   if (elementCount.containsKey(theArray[i]) {
     elementCount.put(theArray[i], new Integer(elementCount.get(theArray[i]) + 1));
   } else {
     elementCount.put(theArray[i], new Integer(1));
   }
}

List<Integer> moreThanOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer key : elementCount.keySet()) { // method may be getKeySet(), can't remember
   if (elementCount.get(key) > 1) {
      moreThanOne.add(key);
   }
}

// do whatever you want with the moreThanOne list
```

Notice that this method requires iterating through the list twice (I'm sure there's a way to do it iterating once). It iterates once through `theArray`, and then implicitly again as it iterates through the key set of `elementCount`, which if no two elements are the same, will be exactly as large. However, iterating through the same list twice serially is still O(n) instead of O(n^2), and thus has much better asymptotic running time.

Comment: It's O(n) on average; in the worst case (which is admittedly *much* less likely) this is still O(n^2).

Comment: How is it O(n^2)? Iterating through a list twice in a row is O(n). And `HashMap` gives constant time performance for `.containsKey()`.

Comment: @smessing: I think *dlev* refers to the case where all the elements in the array would generate collisions in the hashtable, in which case the *put* becomes *O(n)* instead of *O(1)*.

Comment: @TacticalCoder Ah! I hadn't thought about that. Good point. But in this situation, an amortized analysis would still yield O(n), no?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what you want. If you run it using the array `{2, 2, 2, 2}`, you'll find that it returns 2 instead of 1. You'll have to find a way to make sure that the counting is never repeated.

However, your Big O expression is correct as a worst-case analysis, since every element *might* be compared with every other element.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct but you could easily get it down to O(n) time.  Try using a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` to store previously-seen values as you iterate through the array (key is the number that you've seen, value is the number of times you've seen it).  Each time you try to add an integer into the hashmap, check to see if it's already there.  If it is, just increment that integers counter.  Then, at the end, loop through the map and count the number of times you see a key with a corresponding value higher than 1.

Comment: This would definitly not produce an algorithm with O(n) complexity

Comment: Checking for presence in a `Map` is constant time, so there's no slowdown associated.

Comment: Yes it would give you O(n).  HashMaps have O(1) inserts/removes/gets/contains.  If you can have at most n items in the map and iterate over the array once, then in the worst case, your HashMap will have one key for every number in the array, hence the map will be of size N.  To iterate over both would take O(2*n) == O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I think your time complexity of `O(n^2)` is correct.

If space complexity is not the issue then you can have an array of 256 characters(ASCII) standard and start filling it with values. For example
// Maybe you might need to initialize all the values to 0. I don't know. But the following can be done with `O(n+m)` where n is the length of theArray and m is the length of array.

> int[] array = new int[256];
>
> for(int i = 0 ; i < theArray.length(); i++)
>
> ```
>   array[theArray[i]] = array[theArray[i]] + 1;
> ```
>
> for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length(); i++)
>
> ```
>   if(array[i] > 1)
>
>         System.out.print(i);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First, your approach is what I would call "brute force", and it is indeed O(n^2) in the worst case. It's also incorrectly implemented, since numbers that repeat n times are counted n-1 times.

Setting that aside, there are a number of ways to approach the problem. The first (that a number of answers have suggested) is to iterate the array, and using a map to keep track of how many times the given element has been seen. Assuming the map uses a hash table for the underlying storage, the average-case complexity should be O(n), since gets and inserts from the map should be O(1) on average, and you only need to iterate the list and map once each. Note that this is still O(n^2) in the worst case, since there's no guarantee that the hashing will produce contant-time results.

Another approach would be to simply sort the array first, and then iterate the sorted array looking for duplicates. This approach is entirely dependent on the sort method chosen, and can be anywhere from O(n^2) (for a naive bubble sort) to O(n log n) worst case (for a merge sort) to O(n log n) average-though-likely case (for a quicksort.)

That's the best you can do with the sorting approach assuming arbitrary objects in the array. Since your example involves integers, though, you can do much better by using radix sort, which will have worst-case complexity of O(dn), where d is essentially constant (since it maxes out at 9 for 32-bit integers.)

Finally, if you know that the elements are integers, and that their magnitude isn't too large, you can improve the map-based solution by using an array of size ElementMax, which would guarantee O(n) worst-case complexity, with the trade-off of requiring 4*ElementMax additional bytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, an O(n) solution is quite possible using a hash. In Perl:

```
my @data = (2,3,2,5,6,1,3);
my %count;
$count{$_}++ for @data;
my $n = grep $_ > 1, values %count;
print "$n numbers are not unique\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2 numbers are not unique
```